# Synchronous call to Rest API in polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer-2.x

Can any body tell me as how to make synchronous calls to Rest services in polymer 2.0.

I am trying calculate client total balance which I can do only after receiving response from all below three Rest services.

Is there any way to synchronize them using some api e.g. Promise or anyother

```
<iron-ajax id="balanceAjax" url="/balances" last-response="{{res1}}"></iron-ajax>
<iron-ajax id="currencyAjax" url="/currencies" last-response="{{res2}}"></iron-ajax>
<iron-ajax id="rateAjax" url="/rates" last-response="{{res3}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have same observer function for all the three properties (res1,2 and 3) and in observer if all of them have some value then proceed and calculate the value.

```
res1: {
   observer: 'responseChanged'
},
res2: {
   observer: 'responseChanged'
}
res3: {
   observer: 'responseChanged'
},
...
responseChanged: function() {
   if(this.res1 && this.res2 && this.res3) {
      //calculate total balance
   }
}
```

You can also have one single observer instead of three

```
res1: {
},
res2: {
}
res3: {
},
...
observers: [responseChanged(res1, res2, res3)],
responseChanged: function() {
   if(this.res1 && this.res2 && this.res3) {
      //calculate total balance
   }
}
```

Alternately, you can also use `on-response` listener of `iron-ajax`.
Lastly, if your res1 ,2 and 3 are expected to have value even before the api call you can set some booleans in `on-response` listener of each ajax and have observer on those booleans instead.